# RISmed package error: Error in any(is.na(WhichArgs)) || sapply(WhichArgs, length) > 1 : 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r, pubmed

```
library(RISmed)
search_topic <- "gestational disease"
mindate <- "2018/01/01"
maxdate <- "2023/12/31"
search_result <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic, db = "pubmed", type = "esearch", mindate = mindate, maxdate = maxdate)
```

It pops out the following error:
Error in any(is.na(WhichArgs)) || sapply(WhichArgs, length) > 1 :
'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

ANY Help is appreciated sincerely:)